# Configuring AzureTableStorage Serilog sink from config file

Tags: serilog

Can the Azure Table Storage sink for Serilog be configured via the app/Web.config like other sinks, eg Elasticsearch and Seq,  which can be configured from the configuration files.

The github page for AzureTableStorage sink shows only code based configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out:

```
<add key="serilog:using" value="Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureTableStorageWithProperties.connectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=someaccount;AccountKey=uJeYNoa/4dKKtH3zG+7YlA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureTableStorageWithProperties.storageTableName" value="my-logs" />
```

With this, am able to see the logs coming in StorageExplorer